# Can you disable ambient display when you have an Android Wear device connected?

Tags: notifications, android-wear

I have *Ambient Display* enabled for *New Notifications* which I really like. However, I also have an Android Wear smart watch and when that is connected the *Ambient Display* notifications are pretty redundant. Is there a way to toggle this setting if the Wear device is connected? I don't wear the watch all the time so when I am not I would like the notifications to resume.

Comment: This seems like something you might be able to do with Tasker, but I'm not sure if Tasker can access that setting.

Comment: Try [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) automation app. Trigger: Android wear connect ; Action: Ambient display off. This needs root. If you don't have  root , you can give elevated privileges [using ADB](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/macrodroid/granting-write_secure_settings-permission-via-adb-t2923.html) . I don't have Android wear to test. Try it out (App is free)